# @property question

Tags: objective-c

In my implementation I have getters and setters like below. I want to use properties and synthesize the getters and setters but have a few questions.

```
- (NSString *)title {
return title;
}

- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)value {
if(title != value) {
    [title release];
    title = [value retain];
}
}
```

If I was to convert that to a property, what attributes would I use? Am I right in thinking:

- **readwrite** so both getters and setters are present
- **retain** so that it increase the retain value of the value string so the object don't lose it.

Am I right with the above?

One final thing. I have the method below ...

```
- (void)setReleaseDate:(NSString *)value {
// YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS +HHMM
if([releaseDate description] != value) {
    [releaseDate release];
    releaseDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithString:value];
}
}
```

Am I right in thinking I still have to include that method because it contains code that the synthesized getter would not include?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your title property, you can declare it in your class interface as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* title;
```

Which is the same as the following:

```
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) NSString* title;
```

**readwrite** is a default setting. Most of the time you will want setters for your properties, so for the times when you don't you would use the non-default **readonly** to specify this.

The **nonatomic** part basically means that the accessors will be faster, and is typically used. You can find out more information about this here: [What does the property "Nonatomic" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821692/what-does-the-property-nonatomic-mean).

For your second question, you can implement your own accessors if you wish. If you do this then it kind of 'overrides' the accessor that would be generated by Objective-C. Remember that you have to keep to the naming conventions. So in your example, the "setReleaseDate:" method you've defined would be used for the setter method for the property "releaseDate" - which is completely correct! :) The problem you have though is that you're passing an *NSString** to set the date, which means that this method won't override the default setter that would be used if you synthesized the property. You have to pass a value of the same type as the one you're setting as the single argument, so for this case you would have to pass an *NSDate**.

You must also ensure that if you provide your own implementation of an accessor that it does what is declared in the interface. I presume your *releaseDate* property should be declared as retain.

Comment: If I provide my own implementation of the releaseDate accessor, in my case I know I will be overriding the default, should I create the property as read so that it don't create the accessor? Although, I think for the sake of correctness passing in an NSDate would seem like the right thing to do. Any advice?

Comment: Passing in an `NSDate` would be the right thing to do, but there's nothing wrong with also having a convenience method that does the string translation. You need to distinguish between the property declaration and the synthesized methods: the property is still `readwrite`, because you can write to it. You want to be able to use dot syntax to assign: `self.releaseDate = x` won't work for `readonly`. `@synthesize` will only create an implementation when you haven't already, so it's safe (eg) to write your own setter and use `@synthesize` to create the getter.

Comment: `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* title;` is not the same as `@property (readwrite, nonatomic) NSString* title;`. The compiler will show a warning too. If there is no retain, assign or copy then he will assume that you meant assign. And assign is definitely not the same as retain.

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion about using `readwrite` as well as `retain` is correct as it would create semantically equivalent code to what you have posted.

The releasedate property setter can't be synthesized as you're transforming a `NSString` into a `NSDate` to store it, that also avoids common issues with `NSString` properties, for which you'd better use `copy` to avoid problems with `NSMutableString`.

Other than that, your code is fine, except that for string comparison you may want to replace the simple pointer check `!=` with `isEqualToString`, see [Comparing Strings in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881335/comparing-strings-in-cocoa/881377#881377).

Comment: Thank you. Quick question, the with the releaseDate property would I create it read only and manually add the setter? Or would it be best not to add a property for it at all?

Comment: as James Bedford already explained, I would provide acces to the releaseDate via a synthesized NSDate property and have the string method as separate convenience method.

Answer (score 0):

It is common, though not always required, to use `copy` semantics for `NSString` properties, to avoid issues with `NSMutableString` objects being changed behind your back.

Otherwise, you seem to be pretty much on top of it.