# Objective-C hidden instance variables

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Hi I've seen two ways to declare hidden instance variables in the .m file
1)

```
@interface MyClass() 
{
  //my ivars
}
@end
@implementation MyClass 
 //my implementation
@end
```

2)

```
@implementation MyClass
{
 //my ivars
}
 //my implementation
@end
```

Confused as to the difference between the two, and/or coding conventions when it comes to this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You will find your answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172598/best-way-to-define-private-methods-for-a-class-in-objective-c The two options are valid, it just depends with Xcode version (read compiler) you are using. Better to mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: @LucWollants He is asking about instance variables and the linked question is referring to private methods. While they are similar I think that this is a not a duplicate of the above.

Comment: Should have been http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632285/declaration-definition-of-variables-locations-in-objectivec

Answer (score 0):

Good question! You tend to see instance variables declared in the `interface`, but obviously the `implementation` works too. My thoughts on the issue:

1. I think using the `interface` is better practice
2. I ***think*** that ivars declared in the `implementation` are inaccessible to subclasses