# Property 'viewController' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate'

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, xcode6

This is the code, i'm trying to make the 'self.viewController' work, but it is giving me an error. What do i need to do to fix this. I am getting the error as stated above in the header of this thread.

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "Name.h"

    @interface AppDelegate ()

    -(Name *)createNameWithNonsenseDataWithIndex:(int)index;


    @end

    @implementation AppDelegate

    @synthesize tableData;



    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return YES;

        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        //Create dummy data

        NSUInteger numberOfNames = 25;

        self.tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numberOfNames];

        //Create a temporary array of tableData
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numberOfNames; i++) {
            //Create a new name with nonsense data
            Name *tempName = [self createNameWithNonsenseDataWithIndex:1];

            //Add it to the temporary array
            [self.tableData addObject:tempName];

        }

        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc]        
    initWithNibName:@"viewController" bundle:nil];


        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare a property to use `self.viewController`

```
@interface AppDelegate () 
   -(Name *)createNameWithNonsenseDataWithIndex:(int)index;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) ViewController *viewController; 
@end
```

Also as `Haroldo Gondim` mentioned make sure the name of your nib is correct.

> Since Xcode 4.4 you can skip `@synthesize`

[Declaration/definition of variables locations in ObjectiveC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632285/declaration-definition-of-variables-locations-in-objectivec)

Comment: also  you can just call init, as long as the xib has the same name as the view controller class `self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];`

Answer (score 0):

In `Nib` name the name must be exactly the name of your `.xib` File.
Use V with upper case.

```
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc]        
initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no property 'viewController' in your 'AppDelegate' class. 
In your AppDelegate.h under interface declaration you need to have:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewController* viewController;
```

And In your AppDelegate.m under implementation declaration you need to have:

```
@synthesize viewController;
```