# Better Understanding Property Declarations

Tags: objective-c, types, properties

I want to show you an example of one of my header files and get your suggestions on what I could do better giving the situations below.

*ARC is enabled*

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int some_simple_value;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *someArray;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *someButton;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *someArrayCopy
@property BOOL some_bool;
```

I understand what a lot of the types mean, but I don't know why I would use a given one instead of another in some cases. Also, if I know my object is only accessed by one class, should I not use `nonatomic` (because there's no worry of multiple threads accessing it, right?)

## ANSWER

These answers helped me drastically:

[What's the difference between the atomic and nonatomic attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties)

and

[Objective-C declared @property attributes (nonatomic, copy, strong, weak)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859719/xcode-property-attributes-nonatomic-copy-strong-weak)

Comment: I think you'd be better off asking each item as a separate question. There's a lot here for one answer. strong vs weak has nothing to do with nonatomic vs atomic, for example, and there's a lot to be said about both subjects.

Comment: These answers helped me drastically:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties

and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859719/xcode-property-attributes-nonatomic-copy-strong-weak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you *could* read the documentation! :) But if you want a perhaps more friendly instructive explanation, I've written you one:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_properties_2

However, before you read that, you should really read about memory management, earlier in that chapter:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_memory_management

`strong` and `weak` are *very* different indeed; if you understand memory management and ARC, you'll know why.