# How to release GADBannerView on ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I sounds like a stupid question, but it seems I cannot release an adMob GADBannerView.

Admob documentation says don't call "release" when using ARC. Needless to say you cannot call release because it's not allowed and generates an error. 
I tried this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)  GADBannerView *adMobView;
```

…

```
 [adMobView removeFromSuperview];
 adMobView.delegate = nil;
 adMobView = nil;
```

But nothing happens. It becomes nil but still stays on the screen. It supposed to be a subclassed UIView. At the best I can hide it but it still received ads and obviously stays in the memory.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try weak reference

```
 @property (nonatomic, weak)  GADBannerView *adMobView;
```

**Weak**

weak is similar to strong except that it won't increase the reference count by 1. It does not become an owner of that object but just holds a reference to it. If the object's reference count drops to 0, even though you may still be pointing to it here, it will be deallocated from memory.

[Refer more here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9859719/1704346)

Comment: It is released after assignment, compiler even gives me a warning about it. I think it's not the reference count but AdMob SDK simply does not support ARC. Nilling an object does not remove from the memory, it must be waiting for a release but it's illegal in ARC.