# Define ios basic keywords

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I want to know the proper definition working and importance of

`weak,strong,atomic,non-atomic,retain,copy ,reuse,cell-reusable`

Please don't refer me some link.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: thanks Display Name for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below link contain both Good information regarding ios basic property attributes
[Objective-C declared @property attributes (nonatomic, copy, strong, weak)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859719/objective-c-declared-property-attributes-nonatomic-copy-strong-weak)