# Do I have to use nonatomic property in objective-c ios programing?

Tags: iphone, ios, atomic, nonatomic

I'm developing an iPhone app.

All the iPhone development books I have read use nonatomic property.
And IBOutlets which xcode generates also use nonatomic keyword.

But I don't like to write `nonatomic` on every property because it decrease readability too much.

Are there any problem if I do not use `nonatomic` keyword for all properties?

If nonatomic keyword makes my app only a little bit faster, I want to delete all `nonatomic` keywords. 
Is it good idea?

Comment: if you dont use nonatomic and synthesize you can not call that variable in another class.... so it is better to use, not for all but for some.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/atomic-vs-nonatomic-properties http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821692/what-does-the-property-nonatomic-mean Info on what nonatomic actually means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete `nonatomic` from property then by default all your properties will be 'atomic'.
If there are a lot of 'atomic' properties without purpose then it will slow up your app, because at compile time atomic properties generate a complex code and every time you use that property that code will be executed.